# how to end the PostgreSQL create index properly

Tags: postgresql

I am using this command to create index in PostgreSQL 13:

```
CREATE INDEX dict_word_idx ON dict (word);
```

but now the sql runs for more than 12hours, I am not sure the sql still working or something. I use this command to show the current running sql:

```
SELECT 
  procpid, 
  start, 
  now() - start AS lap, 
  current_query 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    backendid, 
    pg_stat_get_backend_pid(S.backendid) AS procpid, 
    pg_stat_get_backend_activity_start(S.backendid) AS start, 
    pg_stat_get_backend_activity(S.backendid) AS current_query 
  FROM 
    (SELECT pg_stat_get_backend_idset() AS backendid) AS S 
  ) AS S 
WHERE 
  current_query <> '<IDLE>' 
ORDER BY 
  lap DESC;
```

shows result of create index like this:

```
1303    2021-10-04 09:24:27 13:12:49.940239 CREATE INDEX dict_word_idx ON dict (word);
```

but the `pg_stat_progress_create_index` shows nothing:

```
select *
from pg_stat_progress_create_index;
```

then I tried to use this sql to kill the create index task:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(1303);
```

It seems not work, the create index command still stand there. what should I do to figure out what's happening right now. The SQL still busy running and I should waiting? the craeted index command should not be killed like this? what should I do to properly handle this situation and do not make the database failed  in the furture.

Comment: Please show the output of `SELECT state, wait_event_type, wait_event FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = 1303;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query for current activity is incredibly obsolete. Since 9.2, the text of completed queries don't get changed to '<IDLE>', they continue to show up as their original query text.  It is there `state` that gets changed to 'idle'.

So most likely what you are seeing is that the index build has already finished.